# Call controller method inside javascript function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Opah!

Is there any way I can call a method in the controller through a javascript code?
I am wanting to destroy a Session to leave a specific page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the simplest way to do this IMO is with javascript, calling

```
$.ajax(url: 'controller/action',success: function(data) { //do whatever with your result... })
```

you can also use $.get(), $.post()...

see [jQuery - Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more.

Comment: It worked! Just put the link on a page edit hidden (Url.Action ()) and it worked. Thank

Success